# How can I determine the width and height of a video without going through the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-video

If I want to determine the width and height of an image, I can do the following:

```
let image = new Image();
image.src = ...the source ;
image.decode();

console.log( image.width, image.height );
```

There is no need to create a DOM element to render the image and then obtain the the dimensions.

Is it possible to do something similar with a video? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what I want:

```
let video = document.createElement( 'video');

video.setAttribute( "preload", "metadata" );

video.src = // ...the data source

video.addEventListener( 'loadeddata', function() {
    console.log( this.videoWidth, this.videoHeight );

});
```

I create the video element, but do not insert it into the DOM. I believe setting the preload attribute does not require the entire video file to be loaded, but I am not certain about that.

The data is loaded and the loadeddata event is triggered, logging the width and height of the video.

I would be interested in knowing what other people thought about this solution.

Comment: Sometimes the browser won't preload the video whatever the attribute, especially mobile browsers on cellular networks.